# Is there a replacement for recordselect gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using recordselect gem to populate a many-to-many association. Does anybody know another gem for the same effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete